# Error upload miniprogram GTR-3 Zepos Android

Tags: android, zeppos

I can't upload the mini program to GTR-3  with Zepp on Android.

I am trying upload simple program

1. zeus build
2. zeus preview
3. scan qr code

but I get the following error. In device:

```
11-26 23:51:26.892  1520  1667 E Watchdog: !@Sync: 2971 heap: 134 / 144 FD: 1088 [2022-11-26 23:51:26.892]
11-26 23:51:26.932  5719 24242 I flutter : *** DioError ***:
11-26 23:51:26.932  5719 24242 I flutter : uri: https://api-mifit-cn2.huami.com/custom/tools/app-dial/download/jhEkavcdaSTJnMxlPgAXGoBimlvyRnOJ?deviceSource=227
11-26 23:51:26.932  5719 24242 I flutter : DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [401]
11-26 23:51:26.932  5719 24242 I flutter : #0      DioMixin.assureDioError (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:819)
11-26 23:51:26.932  5719 24242 I flutter : #1      DioMixin._dispatchRequest (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:678)
11-26 23:51:26.932  5719 24242 I flutter : <asynchronous suspension>
11-26 23:51:26.932  5719 24242 I flutter : #2      DioMixin.fetch.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:586)
11-26 23:51:26.932  5719 24242 I flutter : <asynchronous suspension>
11-26 23:51:26.932  5719 24242 I flutter : uri: https://api-mifit-cn2.huami.com/custom/tools/app-dial/download/jhEkavcdaSTJnMxlPgAXGoBimlvyRnOJ?deviceSource=227
11-26 23:51:26.932  5719 24242 I flutter : statusCode: 401
11-26 23:51:26.932  5719 24242 I flutter : headers:
11-26 23:51:26.932  5719 24242 I flutter :  x-client-hash: ed916f8
11-26 23:51:26.932  5719 24242 I flutter :  connection: keep-alive
11-26 23:51:26.932  5719 24242 I flutter :  date: Sat, 26 Nov 2022 20:51:26 GMT
11-26 23:51:26.932  5719 24242 I flutter :  vary: Origin
11-26 23:51:26.932  5719 24242 I flutter :  content-length: 54
11-26 23:51:26.932  5719 24242 I flutter :  content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
11-26 23:51:26.932  5719 24242 I flutter :  x-client-region: nx
11-26 23:51:26.932  5719 24242 I flutter : 
11-26 23:51:26.932  5719 24242 I flutter :
```

If open url in browser i  get

```
{"message":"apptoken can not be empty"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error code (401) on your log points out to an authentication error

Make sure the following requirements are met in your environment:

1. You have run `zeus login` and you account is active on zeus CLI.
   (You can run zeus login again to check if it's already logged in)
2. You are using the same account on both your zepp app and zeus CLI.
   (You NEED to login with **e-mail/password** DO NOT USE social login buttons)
3. You scanned the QRCode using the Zepp app in the development mode.
   Detailed instructions on how to activate developer mode in the app can be found in [Zepp App Developer Mode](https://docs.zepp.com/docs/1.0/guides/tools/zepp-app/) page